# [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].isMenuVisible always be NO in EGOTextView

Tags: iphone, ios, uimenucontroller

Im employing [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView) to do NSAttributedString editing. There is a bug on `UIMenuController` which I couldn't get over. As the logic described in the following code, the UIMenu will alternately show and hide after a tap on the EGOTextView. But the fact is the `[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].isMenuVisible`  will always get **NO**, that the code `[menuController setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];` will never get called. Is there any tricky thing I have missed? Thanks for any suggestion!

**EGOTextView.m**

```
- (void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture {

NSLog(@"[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].isMenuVisible :%d",[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].isMenuVisible);
// It always log 0 even if the UIMenu is visible on the screen.

if (_editable && ![self isFirstResponder]) {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];  
    return;
}

[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(showMenu) object:nil];
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(showCorrectionMenu) object:nil];

self.correctionRange = NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0);
if (self.selectedRange.length>0) {
    self.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(_selectedRange.location, 0);
}

NSInteger index = [self closestWhiteSpaceIndexToPoint:[gesture locationInView:self]];

if (_delegateRespondsToDidSelectURL && !_editing) {
    if ([self selectedLinkAtIndex:index]) {
        return;
    }
}

UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
NSLog(@"menuController.menuVisible :%d", menuController.menuVisible);

if ([menuController isMenuVisible]) {
// never run into here
    [menuController setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];

} else {

    if (index==self.selectedRange.location) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(showMenu) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.35f];
    } else {
        if (_editing) {
            [self performSelector:@selector(showCorrectionMenu) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.35f];
        }
    }

}

[self.inputDelegate selectionWillChange:self];

self.markedRange = NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0);
self.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(index, 0);

[self.inputDelegate selectionDidChange:self];
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the code below, and **[menuController setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];** should be the point that set UIMenuController invisible.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer")]) {
        UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        if ([menuController isMenuVisible]) {
            [menuController setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];
        }
    }

    return NO;

}
```

The function **- (void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture**  is run after - **(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer** .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to search "setMenuVisible:NO". It must also be written at somewhere else.